# Regex match string words

Tags: php, regex

I have the following:

```
<?php

$searchExpression = 'hello there yo\'s -3 "hey"';

preg_match_all("/\"([^\]]*)\"/", $searchExpression, $exact_words);

var_dump($exact_words[1]);

echo '<br><br>';

preg_match_all("/(-\d+)/", $searchExpression, $blabla);

var_dump($blabla[1]);
```

These matches

```
-3
"hey"
```

How can I match the other words `"hello", "there", "yo's"?` These can be any string word.

Comment: use `\b` to match on word boundaries. `/\b(.*?)\b/`?

Comment: You could explode on whitespace if you just want everything separated. https://eval.in/434523

Comment: @MarcB That matches whole string, basically.

Comment: `.*?` is a non-greedy match.

Comment: @MarcB: but it does match empty strings and non-words, as it matches from the end of the word until the begging of the next one (that could be expressed as `\b\W*\b`). [Demo online](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/cF3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following technique: match what you do not want to return and fail the match manually with `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs, and then match whatever you need.

Here is a sample regex:

```
(?:-\d+|"[^"]*")(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC9eI9/1)

The `(?:-\d+|"[^"]*")` will be skipped and `\S+` will match all sequences of non-whitespace characters.

[IDEONE Demo](http://ideone.com/gkSXMJ):

```
$re = '/(?:-\d+|"[^"]*")(*SKIP)(*F)|\S+/'; 
$str = "hello there yo\'s -3 \"hey\""; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use explode, split or preg_split.

explode uses a fixed string:

```
$parts = explode(' ', $string);
```

while split and preg_split use a regular expression:

```
$parts = split(' +', $string);
$parts = preg_split('/ +/', $string);
```

An example where the regular expression based splitting is useful:

```
$string = 'hello there yo\'s -3 "hey"';
var_dump(explode(' ', $string));
var_dump(split(' +', $string));
var_dump(preg_split('/ +/', $string));
```